# Custom user themes in multi-tenant architecture

Tags: architecture

I'm in the process of architecting a multi-tenant web application that will consist of the following separate components:

- Core RESTful API (Spring Boot)
- Admin web portal (Angular)
- Front end web UI (will be different for each tenant, tech/language TBD)

The front end web UI needs to support custom user themes. In other words, users will have the ability to create their own themes and upload them to the app (through the admin portal), which would then be used when rendering their front end web UI.

A good example of this is something like Shopify - if users A and B visit their individual storefronts (i.e., `shopA.shopify.com` and `shopB.shopify.com`), their stores will be rendered using their respective custom themes. However, both storefronts still interact with the same core API (as far as I'm aware).

Currently, I have something like this in mind for the high-level architecture:

[image: High-level architecture]

In this example, the core API and admin UI can be hosted as single instances, but each tenant would have their own front end UI instance in order to support custom themes. However, I would really like to try avoid having separate front end UI instances if possible, as I believe it becomes harder to manage from a scalability perspective, and will likely cost more to host.

I've been exploring the following alternative approaches:

- Have 1 UI instance that stores all themes locally, and switches based on the current tenant. My concern with this is that I'm targeting a large number of users, and therefore could have 1000's of themes.
- Store themes in a central location (i.e., something like S3), and whenever a request is made to a tenant's front end, grab the relevant theme files. My concern with this is speed/bandwidth implications of retrieving themes on each request. I could look at some caching layer to help mitigate this.
- Use a hybrid approach by having a few UI instances that each host multiple users (i.e., shared hosting). This adds some slight complexity when routing requests though.

**Question:** how do companies like Shopify etc. approach this problem?

Comment: Good point, i’d like to know.